# How to increase size of span to fill the ul

Tags: html, css

I have a span tag with the class="book_consultation". This is found within a li which is within a ul. So the code looks like:

```html
<ul class="pre-header">
  <li><span class="book_consultation">Book Consultation<span></li>
</ul>
```

Now the `pre-header` is the length of the screen (looks like a banner) and the `book_consultation` is the text.

The issue I have is that the only clickable text is the link. So if user taps on the text, it opens a form, but if they click outside the text in the `pre-header`, nothing happens. I want the whole pre-header to be clickable so that it opens the form.

I am not sure how in CSS to make the `book-consultation` area to be as wide as pre-header. It doesn't mean I want the text to stretch, I just want the `pre-header` to be clickable and my thinking is expanding the clickable area of `book_consultation`.

I tried setting the width of book_consultation to 100% but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: You must have JavaScript or some code to make the `span` clickable. Just apply that code to the `ul` instead...

Comment: where is your link in the code you shared ? i do not see any <a> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

span is an inline element.  It needs to be block for full width. For full-width use:

```
.pre-header .book_consultation
{ display: block;
}
```

Also, a small thing, you need to do

```
</span>
```

on your closing span tag.

Answer (score 2):

Span is an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) and will not take up full width. Exchange `span` for a `p`          or give the span a `display:block`.

```css
.pre-header li {
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.1)
}

.pre-header li span,
.pre-header li p {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.preheader--3 span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pre-header preheader--1">
  <li><span class="book_consultation">Book Consultation</span></li>
</ul>

<ul class="pre-header preheader--2">
  <li><p class="book_consultation">Book Consultation</p></li>
</ul>

<ul class="pre-header preheader--3">
  <li><span class="book_consultation">Book Consultation</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

the browser adds **margin-block-*** and **padding-inline-start** by default to ul elements.You need to override those properties to get rid of extra space.

```css
.pre-header{
  list-style-type:none;
  border:1px solid gray;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.book_consultation{
  display:block;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}

.book_consultation:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pre-header">
  <li><span class="book_consultation">Book Consultation</span></li>
</ul>
```